# Invalid configuration `noarch-redhat-linux-gnu': machine `noarch-redhat' not recognized

Tags: apache-2.2, centos, redhat, httpd

When I try to build rpm from src rpm (Apache 2.4.1) I got this error:

```
rpmbuild -tb httpd-2.4.1.tar.bz2 --ba httpd.spec
```

> ```
> + ./configure --build=x86_64-redhat-linux-gnu --host=x86_64-redhat-linux-gnu --target=noarch-redhat-linux-gnu --program-prefix= --prefix=/usr --exec-prefix=/usr --bindir=/usr/bin --sbindir=/usr/sbin --sysconfdir=/etc --datadir=/usr/share --includedir=/usr/include --libdir=/usr/lib64 --libexecdir=/usr/libexec --localstatedir=/var --sharedstatedir=/usr/com --mandir=/usr/share/man --infodir=/usr/share/info --enable-layout=RPM --libdir=/usr/lib64 --sysconfdir=/etc/httpd/conf --includedir=/usr/include/httpd --libexecdir=/usr/lib64/httpd/modules --datadir=/var/www --with-installbuilddir=/usr/lib64/httpd/build --enable-mpms-shared=all --with-apr=/usr --with-apr-util=/usr --enable-suexec --with-suexec --with-suexec-caller=apache --with-suexec-docroot=/var/www --with-suexec-logfile=/var/log/httpd/suexec.log --with-suexec-bin=/usr/sbin/suexec --with-suexec-uidmin=500 --with-suexec-gidmin=100 --enable-pie --with-pcre --enable-mods-shared=all --enable-ssl --with-ssl --enable-socache-dc --enable-bucketeer --enable-case-filter --enable-case-filter-in --disable-imagemap
> checking for chosen layout... RPM
> checking for working mkdir -p... yes
> checking for grep that handles long lines and -e... /bin/grep
> checking for egrep... /bin/grep -E
> checking build system type... x86_64-redhat-linux-gnu
> checking host system type... x86_64-redhat-linux-gnu
> checking target system type... Invalid configuration `noarch-redhat-linux-gnu': machine `noarch-redhat' not recognized
> configure: error: /bin/sh build/config.sub noarch-redhat-linux-gnu failed
> błąd: Błędny stan wyjścia z /var/tmp/rpm-tmp.48153 (%build)
>
>
> Błędy budowania RPM-a:
>     Błędny stan wyjścia z /var/tmp/rpm-tmp.48153 (%build)
> ```

Answer (score 1):

I'm also trying to rpmbuild the Apache 2.4.1 on CentOS 5.5, and I solved that error with modifying the http.spec file:

```
%configure \
        --target=x86 \
        --enable-layout=RPM \
```

The line with the --target is added. Compilation is running fine, so far.

Answer (score 0):

From what you have posted it looks as if `noarch-redhat-linux-gnu` is not a recognized `target` parameter.

I see you are on a `x86_64` machine. Have you tried running `./configure` with `target=x86_64-redhat-linux-gnu` ?

Comment: Yes. The same...

Answer (score 0):

To fix building `automake 2.69` on an old legacy RPM based Linux the following was needed in the `spec` file:

```
%configure \
        --target=x86_64-pc-none \
        --host=x86_64-pc-none \
        --build=x86_64-pc-none \
        ........
```